# cross domain jsonp not returning results

Tags: jsonp

i am making cross domain jsonp call to send the data i want and receive whatever the desired results. I am using my php front end in `localhost` to send json request to my django backend thats in `localhost:8000` . Previously i was using ajax but due to cross domain issues i swtiched over to json but it does not seems to return anything .

```
$(document).on('click', '.miloginme', function(event) {

        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        var token = $('#token').val();


var url ="http://localhost:8000/beemer/login/";

  $.getJSON( url, {
    username: username,
    token: token
  })
  .done(function( data ) {
alert(data);
    });  
});
```

Comment: May be you are missing this : 

[Stackoverflow Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659807/callback-not-getting-called-on-internet-explorer-for-ajax-jsonp-call)

Answer (score 0):

For your reference here i attached the simple JSONP response from the Cross domains and bind the values in our UserInterface.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://githubbadge.appspot.com/Jebasuthan',
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(json) {
    console.log(json);
    var result = '<h3>Name: ' + json.user.login + '</h3>' +
                 '<p>Forked Repository: ' + json.fork_repos + '</p>' +
                 '<p>Languages: ' + json.languages + '</p>' +
                 '<p>Email-Id: ' + json.user.email + '</p>' +
                 '<p>Location: ' + json.user.location + '</p>' +
                 '<p>Last Updated Date: ' + json.user.updated_at + '</p>' +
                 '<p>Blog: <a target="_blank" href='+ json.user.blog + '>' + json.user.blog + '</a></p>';
       $('#badge').append(result);
  }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/9eV8s/1/)